# Is there something similar like pandas DataFrame.hist() method that creates connected subplots for barcharts?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I like how the DataFrame method `hist` selects all numeric columns in a DataFrame and then simply returns a comprehensive plot of histogram subplots. With code as simple and effective as this:

```py
df.hist(bins=50, figsize=(15,10))
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I can't seem to create something similar for all categorical columns that simply returns a plot of barchart subplots.

```py
df.select_dtypes("object").plot(kind="bar", subplots=True) # Error because not numeric values
```

Is there some variation for the code above so that it works? How is the `subplots` argument actually used?

Or is there else another similarly quicky and simple way to get what I'm seeking?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `value_counts` to get the count of each categorical variables:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import zip_longest

cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns
ncols = 3
nrows = len(cols) // ncols + (len(cols) % 3 != 0)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, figsize=(4*ncols, 4*nrows))

for col, ax in zip_longest(cols, axs.flat):
    if col:
        df[col].value_counts(sort=False).plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, rot=45, title=col)
    else:
        fig.delaxes(ax)
    
plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's really good. There are just two things. First, I have a lot of columns. 25 in total. It gets very unreadable. I use figsize to help. Is there any way to resize automatically? Take as much space as needed to be readable. Second, is there a way to remove the last row's empty plots?

Comment: Yes, that's great! Maybe just add the title to each plot and then that's it. Although it is a bit hackier than I hoped. But still, very grateful to have the result I needed! ❤️